# Replace Left and Right Click for Alt+1 and Alt+2 (Autohotkey)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I want to send click when I press hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> key + <kbd>1</kbd>, and then, still holding the <kbd>alt</kbd> key send right-click when press the <kbd>2</kbd> key

my code

```
!q::

Send {LButton Down}

KeyWait q

Send {LButton Up}

Return

!w::

Send {RButton Down}

KeyWait w

Send {RButton Up}

Return
```

the idea is to always have pressed the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key,

example :

```
!:: { q::
Send {LButton Down}

KeyWait q 

Send {LButton Up}

w:: 

Send {RButton Down} 

KeyWait w 

Send {RButton Up} 

KeyWait ! 

Return 

}
```

Help me please

Comment: the second code does not work

Comment: Why not "Kick off" the script with Alt+1, do your thing, then wait for "just" 2 (not Alt+2) to continue the script. You could test the next input and if it is not a number (i.e. you started doing something else), break out of the script. Alternatively, if you want to use Alt+2, you could first test the key state of Alt (Down).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested some code and I came to this conclusion.
You should avoid using alt key cause (you can test it) it will cause to disappear the right click menu (right click in desktop without any ahk app running. then press alt, you see that the menu disappears.)
So here I use the Ctrl key.

The only thing you had to add was a `$` prefix. same as below:

```
$^1::
    send, {lbutton down}
    keywait, 1
    send, {lbutton up}
return

$^2::
    send, {rbutton down}
    keywait, 2
    send, {rbutton up}
return
```

Its with `Ctrl` key and you can not use `Alt` key cause it disables the flying out menu. You can use `!` alt key instead of ctrl key but you have to first release `alt` then release `2` to prevent that menu from disappearing.

I think what you want is something like this. I figured out why it was sending repetitively and took care of it. but it does not work either. maybe the alt key is autosending itself (i mean naturally its behavior is like this).

```
$ALT::
    send, {alt down}
    keywait, ALT
return

$ALT UP::
    send, {alt up}
return

$!1::
    send, {lbutton down}
    keywait, 1
    send, {lbutton up}
return

$!2::
    send, {rbutton down}
    keywait, 2
    send, {rbutton up}
return
```

Another Solution is to use a key in place of the modifier:

```
$1::
    if GetKeyState("z", "p") {
        send, {lbutton down}
        keywait, 1
        send, {lbutton up}
    }
    else {
        SetKeyDelay, -1
        Send {Blind}{1 DownTemp}
    }
return

$1 up::
    SetKeyDelay, -1
    Send {Blind}{1 Up}
return

$2::
    if GetKeyState("z", "p") {
        send, {rbutton down}
        keywait, 2
        send, {rbutton up}
    }
    else {
        SetKeyDelay, -1
        Send {Blind}{2 DownTemp}
    }
return

$2 up::
    SetKeyDelay, -1
    Send {Blind}{2 Up}
return
```

you can use any key instead of `"z"`. `z` is like the `alt` key.

Comment: thank you very much, the first code works perfectly, and if replacement "^" to "!" does not work, the second code has a problem to appear the contextual menu

Comment: @dcaro Which key do you prefer in place of alt?

Comment: i use your script with Win key now, I prefer  Win key by location or Ctrl Right

Comment: @dcaro a new solution I added. you can use the key above `alt` (here `z`, in my keyboard actually) as it were the `alt` key.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
!1::Click

!2::Click Right
```

Comment: good, but holding click? and [hold alt] + [1] (send click) and still holding alt, press 2 to send Click Right  :(  maybe is imposible